# sort my file paths according to their date of creation?

Tags: python, file, tkinter

I wrote a function that display me in a tkinter Label all files in a directory with each last modification date.

i want those files be sorted ascending in my label, i tried with sorted() method, but it doesnt work.

There is my function :

```
def CheckModifyTime():

    path = "C:\\Users\\sohei\\Desktop\\Perso\\TestScriptWinSCP"
    myDir = os.listdir(path)
    window = tk.Toplevel(GuiInterface)
    window.geometry("800x800")
    today = date.today()
    for root, dirs , files in os.walk(path):
        for f in files:
            myFiles = os.path.join(root, f)
            modifyTime = myFiles + " " + time.ctime(os.path.getmtime(myFiles))
            
            #print(modifyTime)
            myVar = StringVar()
            myVar.set(modifyTime)
            label = tk.Entry(window , textvariable = myVar , width = "100").pack()
```

and with the `sorted()` Method :

```
def CheckModifyTime():

    path = "C:\\Users\\sohei\\Desktop\\Perso\\TestScriptWinSCP"
    myDir = os.listdir(path)
    window = tk.Toplevel(GuiInterface)
    window.geometry("800x800")
    today = date.today()
    for root, dirs , files in os.walk(path):
        for f in files:
            
            myFiles = os.path.join(root, f)
            modifyTime = myFiles + " " + time.ctime(os.path.getmtime(myFiles))
            
            #print(modifyTime)
            myVar = StringVar()
            
            sortedFiles = sorted(modifyTime , key=lambda t: os.stat(t).st_mtime)
            myVar.set(sortedFiles)
            print(sortedFiles)
            label = tk.Entry(window , textvariable = myVar , width = "100").pack()
```

Do you have an idea to sort my files ?

Comment: Unless I'm missing something here, you're trying to "sort" a single object on each iteration. Why is "myFiles" a plural? It's a path. It's one thing. check your variable names then probably it will make more sense what's going on.

Comment: @Neil yeah i fixed my problem, really easy but i was on my code for 5 hours now that i didnt notice it was that easy , thanks

Answer (score 0):

I would make an object for them.

```
class DatedFile:
    def __init__(self, name, date):
        self.name = name
        self.date = date
    def __lt__(self, other):
        return self.date<self.other
```

The **lt** method is a built-in 'magic' function that is called upon whenever the 'less than' operator is used.  This is important because the sort and sorted functions actually just runs a lot of a<b's so if you have that method in a class, you can sort it like anything else.

Then put all your files with dates into a list made of instances of this class.

```
my_files = []
for f in files:
    my_files.append(DatedFile(name, date))
my_files.sort()
```

And then it will sort them by date and you can access their variables like any other class (.name and .date)

Let me know if that helps or if you have any questions of need more examples!